# What is the meaning of dash?

Tags: bash, sh

```
mongodump -db somedb --collection somecollection --out - | gzip > dump.gz
```

What is the dash mean in above picture? I seems something to do with tunnel. But after looking up bash reference, i still can't get what't the meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means output goes to the stdout, so the pipe would pass it to the `gzip`. And it's not about `bash(1)`, it's up to the program `mongodump`. In unix and linux, the dash `-` related to input or output, usually stands for `stdin` or `stdout`.

Answer (score 3):

oxnz is right on target. To expand upon that a little bit, some commands want a file as an argument typically at the end. In the command you describe, `mongodump` is hoping to output a file.

That's great, but your intent is to just compress it into a file dump_xyz. So instead of mongodump take a file as the final argument, the `-` indicates standard output (depending on the context, `-` can mean standard input). The output of mongodump directly goes to the standard output and pipes right into the waiting gzip. Gzip takes mongodump's output, compresses it on the fly and stores the compressed information into dump_xyz file.

Here's some light reading about `-` special character: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#DASHREF2

Comment: Great explanation. +1 for both of you. :)